# How to store likes using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a backend on firebase and there are something like post like in Facebook. So I need functionality liking these posts. The question is how to store likes and user who liked the post?
All help will be appreciated

Comment: @luk2302 I just want to know how it would be theoretically. I don't need a code

Comment: The same logic applies to "theoretical" question: what thoughts and concepts have you come up with on your own yet?

Comment: @luke2302 Each post has a field, where I can store likes as array of objects

Comment: @luke2302 I thought there is a better way to do that

Comment: Please edit that into your question so everybody can see it easily - I personally have no idea about firebase, just trying to improve your question so the chances are higher for you getting a helpful answer.

Answer (score 14):

Take this data structure:

```
{
   "posts": {
      "post_1": {
         "uid": "user_1",
         "title": "Cool Post"
      },
      "post_2": {
         "uid": "user_1",
         "title": "Another Cool Post"
      },
      "post_3": {
         "uid": "user_2",
         "title": "My Cool Post"
      }
   },
   "postLikes": {
      "user_1": {
         "post_3": true
      },
      "user_2": {
         "post_1": true,
         "post_2": true         
      }
   }
}
```

The location `/posts` retrieves all the posts.
The location `/postLikes` retrieves all the likes on posts.

So let's say you're `user_1`. To get the posts `user_1` has liked you could write this Firebase database listener:

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "<my-firebase-app>")
let uid = "user_1"
let userRef = ref.childByAppendingPath(uid)
userRef.observeEventType(.Value) { (snap: FDataSnapshot!) in
  print(snap.value) // prints all of the likes

  // loop through each like
  for child in snap.children {
    let childSnap = child as! FDataSnapshot
    print(childSnap.value) // print a single like
  }
}
```

**What's important to note here is the "flatness" of the data structure.** The `postLikes` are not stored under each `post`. This means that you can retrieve a `post` without getting all of its likes. But, if you want to get both, you can still do that since you know the user's id.

[**Try giving the Firebase guide on Structuring Data a read through**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data)

Comment: Thank you, David. One more question, how to fetch number of likes of post?

Comment: With the snapshot, you can access `snap.childrenCount`. However, this just a count of all the data downloaded. There isn't a way to just return the count.

Comment: Not sure, it's really hard for me :). In your answer I can store likes, but can't count how many times the post was liked. Or I didn't understand something

Comment: You could also keep a "likeCount" within each post.  When the client "likes" a post, you could increment that value client-side and push it back to the post.  Make sure to handle race conditions though.

Comment: @DavidEast hello, David. If I'm using ur technology of fan-out. Should i store likes count in each post and on each like update likes count in each post on server side? Or It's better to store it as another node? and for each post get likes count from this node?

Comment: @Josh I'm currently facing this issue, how do you avoid race conditions in such a scenario?

Comment: "user_1" is stored as a document inside "postLikes" collection, which will work fine for a small number of likes but if likes are in millions, will this approach work?

Answer (score 8):

To add to the comments in david's answer, above (I can't add a comment yet) to get the count for likes, you want to use transactional data.

In your firebase, you want to set up a "likes" child, looks something like this in the post node:

```
{
   "posts": {
      "post_1": {
         "uid": "user_1",
         "title": "Cool Post"
         "likes": 0
      },
      "post_2": {
         "uid": "user_1",
         "title": "Another Cool Post"
         "likes": 0
      },
      "post_3": {
         "uid": "user_2",
         "title": "My Cool Post"
         "likes": 0
      }
```

The code in Xcode looks something similar to below. You would be adding a counter every time the post is liked (same code, but use "- 1" to unlike).

```
self.databaseRef.child("posts").child("post_1").child("likes").runTransactionBlock({
         (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
         var value = currentData.value as? Int
                               //check to see if the likes node exists, if not give value of 0.
                                if (value == nil) {
                                    value = 0
                                }
                                currentData.value = value! + 1
                                return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)

                            })
```

Hope this helps someone!

Additional reading for this sort of counter:

[Upvote/Downvote system within Swift via Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061536/upvote-downvote-system-within-swift-via-firebase)

[Follower counter not updating node in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601296/follower-counter-not-updating-node-in-firebase)

Comment: Your given code allows user to multy like on thing :)

Comment: yes--to downvote/unlike run similar code but                                  currentData.value = value! - 1

Answer (score 1):

i think the best way to store likes is to create an array variable...then push their uid...
if they unlike just pull out their uid... the size of the array will be the numbers of likes. this way you will have no duplicates.

```
 "post_1": {
     "uid": "user_1",
     "title": "Cool Post"
     "likes": []
  }
```

post_1.likes.push(user.uid)