# Follower counter not updating node in firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have been trying to implement a "follow" function on my app. Essentially when a user hits the "follow" button, we run a `runTransactionBlock` to update integer values we are storing on Firebase database for the user and the account they are following. **The issue is that I am able to update the counter for the user (say John in example below) , but I am not able to update the counter for the user I am following (say olivia in example below).**

Currently the Firebase nodes look as such:

```
user_profiles{
      UID1:{
           name: john
           following: 1 //code will update for my account
           followers: 0
      },
      UID2:{
           name: olivia
           following: 0
           followers: 0 //code will not update count for person i am trying to follow
```

I have referenced the following, however I am still facing issues with getting this to work. If anyone can please glance through and point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/saving-data.html

[Firebase database help - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37148898/firebase-database-help-swift)

[Upvote/Downvote system within Swift via Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061536/upvote-downvote-system-within-swift-via-firebase)

```
var guestUIDToPass = String()
var loggedInUser = AnyObject()

@IBAction func didTapFollow(sender: AnyObject) {
 following() 
}



func following() {

        self.loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser


//updating count for user, works perfectly        

self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child(self.loggedInUser.uid).child("following").runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
            var value = currentData.value as? Int
            if (value == nil) {
                value = 0
            }
            currentData.value = value! + 1
            return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
        })

//updating count for person user is following, doesn't update firebase

        self.databaseRef.child("user_profiles").child("\(self.guestUIDToPass)").child("followers").runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FIRMutableData!) in
            var value = currentData.value as? Int
            if (value == nil) {
                value = 0
            }
            currentData.value = value! + 1
            return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)

        })
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because `followers` is actually `follower` in your JSON tree..Are you using Swift3?

Comment: @Dravidian double checked they are both the same. I typed up the JSON tree on my question, just updated it. Currently using swift 2

Comment: Make sure you are getting your `guestUIDToPass` right, and why are you using same child `guestUIDToPass` in both transaction?

Comment: Doh! Typed that in wrong on my question just updated it :(. But on Xcode it shows correct. Yes guestUIDToPass is showing the correct string. I even tried hard coding the guest UID into the code with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:-

```
let prntRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user_profiles").child(whomIFollowedUID).child("following")

prntRef.runTransactionBlock({ (following) -> FIRTransactionResult in
    if let followNum = following.value as? Int{

        following.value = followNum + 1
        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(following)
    }else{

        return FIRTransactionResult.successWithValue(following)

    }
    }, andCompletionBlock: {(error,completion,snap) in

            print(error?.localizedDescription)
            print(completion)
            print(snap)
        if !completion {

            print("The value wasn't able to Update")
            }else{
            //Updated
        }
})
```

Comment: This works, thanks! i made a small mod, which was to add another child:  `let prntRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user_profiles").child(whomIFollowedUID).child("following")`